# Is there a way to create a calculated dynamic column in a matrix?

Tags: powerbi

I created the matrix below and I have page filters based on id and month.

Is there a way for me to create a calculated column that does Failures/Flights? I tried creating it as an additional column on my data, but is not dynamic by months/ids filtered.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You need to learn about DAX measures: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need really need a calculated column? if you calculate a measure it should work just fine.

`measureName:= DIVIDE(Failures,Flights)`

Comment: Thank you. I was using the quick measure instead of new measure,